# Using powershell to collect certain columns of data

Tags: powershell

I am having some problems getting windows powershell to do what I want it to do. Essentially, I have 24 subfolders in my current folder, named Angle1, Angle2, etc. up to Angle 24.

In each of these subfolders there is a file called output.txt. In output.txt, there are 10 columns of data, separated by a blank space. I would like to get the 9th column of each output.txt file in each subfolder, and put them all in a new file in parent folder called total.txt. So, ultimately, I would have 24 columns of data, each separated by a space. The first column of total.txt would correspond to the 9th column of output.txt in Angle1, etc.

Note that the Angle folders have other subfolders which I want to ignore.

Despite many attempts, I have not been able to get this to work. I am not sure if I need to use the -Recurse option to do this, or if Powershell is even capable of doing this. IS there anyone here who is an expert at a powershell, that could say whether this is possible or not?

A small except from one output.txt file:

```
1348 2 26.0785 3.18115 20.5328 -0.79613 3.18115 2.51545 4.13292 0.278888 
1348 2 26.8091 2.07125 19.4069 -0.0655152 2.07125 1.38956 2.49505 0.254024 
1348 2 24.162 3.90054 20.4261 -2.71258 3.90054 2.40877 5.32677 0.0208912 
1348 2 24.1527 3.90493 20.4233 -2.72189 3.90493 2.40595 5.33346 0.00646916 
1348 2 24.1436 3.88005 20.4429 -2.73095 3.88005 2.42555 5.32881 0.0127918 
1348 2 24.1087 3.87723 20.4519 -2.76586 3.87723 2.43455 5.34882 0.0198102 
1348 2 24.2572 3.83432 20.4136 -2.61737 3.83432 2.39624 5.22442 0.0243901 
1348 2 24.1609 3.7174 19.8739 -2.71375 3.7174 1.85659 4.9629 0.0838124
```

The code that I was using was in Linux, which worked to some degree:

```
awk '{print $9}' Angle1/output.txt >>tmp
for ((i=2;i<25;i++))
do
awk '{print $9}' Angle${i}/output.txt |paste -d " " tmp - >>total.txt
mv total.txt tmp
done
mv tmp total.txt
```

However, now I need to run in Powershell, not linux. At this time I don't really have any code that remotely works for this. Basically a conglomeration of Get-Child commands etc. but nothing that came close to what I wanted.

Comment: Can you post an example of output.txt and the code that you have tried so far?  This is certainly possible using powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all files have same number of rows:

```powershell
$Results=1..24|ForEach-Object {
    ,@(Get-Content Angle$_\output.txt|ForEach-Object {(-split$_)[8]})
}
&{
    for($i=0;$i-lt$Results[0].Length;++$i){
        @($Results|ForEach-Object {$_[$i]})-join' '
    }
}|Set-Content total.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            $result = @()
    $Anglecount = 0

    do {
    $Anglecount ++
        $content = get-content (".\Angle"+$i+"\output.txt")
        foreach ($line in $content) { 

            $trimmed = $line.Trim()
            $split = $line.Split(" ")
            $result += $split[8]

        }
        $Anglecount
    } until ($Anglecount -eq 24)

    $result | Out-File total.txt
```

Not the most elegant solution but will do the trick for you

Comment: when I save this as a .ps1 and run, it creates total.txt but it is blank

Comment: Yes
Open up the Powershell ISE and paste the code into there for testing.
Then save it as a ps1 file

Comment: sorry, i edited comment. I save as ps1 and ran it. It seemed like it looped through directories, but total.txt was empty

Comment: It says that it is 15kb, but when I open the file, I dont see anything? Strange

Comment: Is it getting the 9th column of data?

Comment: there is a blank space at the end of each line you posted up ... one moment I will adjust the script

Comment: It is saved there. I have Angle1, Angle 2, etc up to Angle24, and below I have the prac.ps1 file. I go to Powershell and do a ./prac.ps1 and it gives me a blank file (it says its 15kb), named total.txt

Comment: ohhh, there is a blank space there? that would make sense. I think your script is probably copying this blank space and thats why the file is 15 kb but I see nothing

Comment: Yes I just noticed that it is also getting the 10th column not the 9th column, ... one moment

Comment: This still does not work unfortutanely. i get a lot of errors:get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\B\Angle\output.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\B\prac2.ps1:6 char:20
+         $content = get-content (".\Angle"+$i+"\output.txt")
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:

Comment: Instead of Angle\output, shouldnt it be Angle1\ouput or something? The last code you posted did not seem to loop through

Comment: Change `$i` to `$Anglecount` when setting `$content`

Comment: @beehaus Hey, the new edit still doesnt work.  Also, I think the $i needs to be change to $Anglecount like Samuel Prout said. It's creating 1 column and not 24

Comment: @beehaus It's almost working. Just I need 24 columns and not 1 in total.txt 

you are helping so much!

Answer (score 0):

If this were comma separated input, this would be dirt simple.  So I created a short script to convert the data to CSV, save it that way, then I show a short example how to use it.

function Get-ColumnData {
    param ([string]$folder)

```
$fileInput = Get-Content -Path "$folder\output.txt"

# initialize an array
$fileOutput = @()

# put title headers for later import as CSV
# I chose arbitrary names, they can be almost anything, but avoid spaces and special characters
$fileOutput += "Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,ColumnA"

foreach ($line in $fileinput) {
    # here's the meat, trim whitespace off the end and replace spaces with commas
    $line = $line.TrimEnd() -replace ' ',','

    # add the results to the array
    $fileoutput += $line
    }
# write to a csv
# there's proabably another way to go from an array of strings to an array of objects, 
#    but saving as a CSV, then importing the CSV is dirt simple
$fileOutput | out-file 'C:\temp1\converted.csv'
$Objects = import-csv 'C:\temp1\converted.csv'

# Select the next to last column
$Objects | Select -ExpandProperty Column9 
}

    $location = "c:\temp1" #set to whatever local or remote path
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $location -Directory
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {
        if (Test-Path $folder\output.txt) {
            $folderColumn = Get-ColumnData $folder
            }
            # at this point you have a column of data but it's stored as a collection of strings
            # need to do something here to add it to your data file and I'm stuck there
        }
```

You would need to find a way from here to get just one column from $Objects and have that be a column for your final answer.